# How to listen to updates on another screen in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Look at the GIF first:

[image]

The 2nd page is listening to the actions on the 1st page. At first, the 2nd page has states: `counter = 2` and `language = Chinese`. But when buttons are pressed on the 1st page, 2nd page's states get updated.

I am using a module called `ReSwift`, if you're familiar with `redux`, it is the Swift version of `redux`. However, I wonder how this can be done without using this module. (I'm not asking how to achieve exactly what's happening in the GIF, but `listen to updates/events on another page` in general, therefore, I hope there's no "hacky" solution).

**If you're interested in the `ReSwift` way, here is the code**

**Things below don't have much to do with the question**

Language.swift:

```
enum Language {
    case English
    case Chinese
}
```

LanguageState.swift:

```
import ReSwift

struct LanguageState: StateType {
    var language: Language = .English
}
```

CounterState.swift:

```
import ReSwift

struct CounterState: StateType {
    var counter: Int = 0
}
```

AppState.swift:

```
import ReSwift

struct AppState: StateType {
    var counterState: CounterState = CounterState()
    var languageState: LanguageState = LanguageState()
}
```

Actions.swift:

```
import ReSwift

struct CounterActionIncrease: Action {}
struct CounterActionDecrease: Action {}
struct ChangeLanguageToEnglish: Action {}
struct ChangeLanguageToChinese: Action {}
```

LanguageReducer.swift:

```
import ReSwift

func LanguageReducer(action: Action, state: LanguageState?) -> LanguageState {
    var state = state ?? LanguageState()

    switch action {
    case _ as ChangeLanguageToEnglish:
        state.language = .English
    case _ as ChangeLanguageToChinese:
        state.language = .Chinese
    default:
        break
    }

    return state
}
```

CounterReducer.swift:

```
import ReSwift

func CounterReducer(action: Action, state: CounterState?) -> CounterState {
    var state = state ?? CounterState()

    switch action {
    case _ as CounterActionIncrease:
        state.counter += 1
    case _ as CounterActionDecrease:
        state.counter -= 1
    default:
        break
    }

    return state
}
```

AppReducer.swift:

```
import ReSwift

func AppReducer(action: Action, state: AppState?) -> AppState {
    return AppState(
        counterState: CounterReducer(action: action, state: state?.counterState),
        languageState: LanguageReducer(action: action, state: state?.languageState)
    )
}
```

Then, in your `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
import UIKit
import ReSwift

let store = Store<AppState>(reducer: AppReducer, state: nil)
...
...
```

Finally, you can subscribe to store in your `ViewControllers` in the standard way

Comment: Where's your question?

Comment: `I wonder how this can be done without using this module` just above the code and the title of this question as well

Comment: I know little about `ReSwift`. But I think you should have a singleton and observe state on it.

Comment: Thanks, I think so too. But then there're other issues, for example, I have two lists of articles, one for each page, and these 2 lists are different, but one article happens to be on both pages. If I delete it on the first page, how can I also make sure that it's deleted on the second page. I'm new to Swift, thanks for being nice!

Comment: You definitely don't need a third-party module to do that, iOS has a number of ways to observe. If the view controllers aren't close enough to each other to use a delegate pattern, use the `NotificationCenter`. You can add a notification observer in `B` and post a notification from `A` whenever a change is made to the view controller's model. `NotificationCenter` allows you to attach objects of type `Any` to the notifications so simply pass `A's` data model with the notification to `B`. You can now make instantaneous changes to `B` using the model from `A`.

Comment: @slickdaddy Awesome, I think that is the answer (event though I still need to learn how `NotificationCenter` works, currently I'm only using it to check if keyboard is showing). If you would post an answer instead of comment on the question, I will accept it. (Unless you don't care about reputation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can paste this into a playground to get a handle of the flow.

```
import UIKit

class ObjectA {
    let interestedData = "slick daddy"
    
    init() {
        updateData()
    }
    
    func updateData() {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("objectADataUpdate"),
                                        object: interestedData)
    }
}

class ObjectB {
    init() {
        addObserver()
    }
    
    func addObserver() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(objectADataUpdateHandler(_:)),
                                               name: Notification.Name("objectADataUpdate"),
                                               object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func objectADataUpdateHandler(_ sender: Notification) {
        guard let data = sender.object as? String else {
            return
        }
        print(data)
    }
}

let b = ObjectB()
let a = ObjectA() // prints "slick daddy"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NotificationCenter` to accomplish that. First we have to create a singleton class and also create a global variable `didUpdateNotificationName` that we are going to use to post events and also to subscribe for events:

```
let didUpdateDataNotificationName = "didUpdateDataNotificationName"

class AppState {

    static var shared = AppState()

    private init(){
        self.counter = 0
        self.language = "English"
    }

    private (set) var counter: Int {
        didSet {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: didUpdateDataNotificationName), object: nil)
        }
    }
    private (set) var language: String {
        didSet {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: didUpdateDataNotificationName), object: nil)
        }
    }

    func update(counter: Int){
        self.counter = counter
    }

    func update(language: String){
        self.language = language
    }

}
```

After that, on each UIViewController you can add a listener for updates:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    self, 
    selector: #selector(updateView), 
    name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: didUpdateDataNotificationName),
    object: nil)
```

Also make sure to implement the method that are going to be executed on each notification, in our case `updateView`:

```
@objc func updateView(){
    label.text = "\(DataModel.shared.counter) \(DataModel.shared.language)"

}
```

Now, every time that you update your variables in `AppState` class, a notification is going to be sent to all observers.

One really important note is that when you're working with notifications, you should remove the observer when you no longer needs it. For instance in the `deinit` method of your class:

```
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(
        self, 
        name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: didUpdateDataNotificationName),
        object: self)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of UITabBarController you can simply access the SecondViewController in FirtsViewController by using the below code

```
var svc:SecondViewController = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[1] as SecondViewController!
```